# Вопрос по стеку и объектам в java

Tags: java, объекты, переменные, методы, стек

Объекты находятся в куче, методы и локальные переменные в стеке, стек со всеми методами начинает выполняться при создании объекта, значит ли это, что стек и, соответственно методы, находятся внутри объекта, который находится внутри кучи?

Comment: Во-первых, методы не находятся в стеке. Во-вторых, стек не выполняется. Выполняются методы, создавая кадры стека и заполняя их локальными переменными. В частности при создании объекта выполняется конструктор. У вас абсолютно неверное представление о принципах работы виртуальной машины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виртуальной машине Java (JVM) модель памяти представлена стеком и кучей. Все объекты где бы и как бы они не создавались хранятся в куче. Следовательно поля объектов хранятся в куче. Локальные же переменные хранятся в стеке, каждый раз при вызове очередного метода, все необходимые локальные переменные (в том числе аргументы функции) заносятся в стек.

Вы же видимо имели ввиду, не хранятся ли локальные переменные метода объекта вместе с самим объектом в куче? Нет, не хранятся.

Несколько пояснений: стек как и куча (в данном контексте) - области хранения, они не выполняются, они просто содержат. Методы не хранятся в стеке. (И в куче тоже. [Согласно этому источнику](https://www.quora.com/How-and-where-are-methods-stored-in-Java) они хранятся во внутренней куче JVM никак не связанной с кучей о которой я писал выше)